# Why is homebrew downloading old geth version?

Tags: go-ethereum, mac-osx

Im on mac OSX, so I go to terminal CLI and do

```
brew install ethereum
```

then I get

```
==> Downloading https://build.ethdev.com/builds/OSX%20Go%20master%20brew/193/bottle/ethereum-1.1.0.yosemite.bottle.193.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring ethereum-1.1.0.yosemite.bottle.193.tar.gz
```

So now I'm left with Ethereum 1.1 , but I need 1.3.1
how do I fix this?

Answer (score 5):

First run

```
brew update
```

To update the "formulae" (this is the  brew-specific word for "catalogue") of all the open source projects it knows.

Then run

```
brew upgrade ethereum
```

(Sometimes you'll need to uninstall and reinstall the formula to make it fully work).

With

```
brew info ethereum
```

You can check what you have installed now.